I want to create something that looks similar to the Pascal's triangle below

How can I do so? I have tried the array method but it isn't working. My problem is the text at the side. I want that to be included as well but the proportions are very off.

Could you post your attempt?  That would give us something to go from.  I'm not quite sure about the text at the side.  Is it just the bottom row, but rotated?  I don't see how that helps.

@Vector You have plenty of answers aboit Pascal's pyramid, like this one

@JeT None of them answered my question. It is ok though, I wasn't aware of the notation given in the answer I accepted

It's just an array.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{array}{@{} c @{\hspace{6em}} *{11}{c} @{}}
1  &&&&&& 1 \\
5  &&&&& 1 && 1 \\
10 &&&& 1 && 2 && 1 \\
10 &&& 1 && 3 && 3 && 1 \\
5  && 1 && 4 && 6 && 4 && 1 \\
1  & 1 && 5 && 10 && 10 && 5 && 1
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}


